# SUM two colmuns from two tables and find highest

Tags: mysql

I want to SUM two columns from two different database and output the highest value.

trying to figure it out since last 1day but no luck. can anyone please help?

```
Table 1    
mid points    
1 20  
2 10 
1 10 
1 30
3 10

Table 2    
mid points    
1 20    
2 10
1 10
2 20
1 10
3 10
```

so the total should be

```
mid points
 1   100
 2   40
 3   20
```

output that i want highest total mid is 1 = 100

Answer (score 1):

Try this untested query:

```
select mid , sum(points) from ( 
    select mid,points from table1 
    union all 
    select mid,points from table2
)  as table3
group by mid 
order by sum(points) DESC 
limit 1
```

Comment: @swap have you tried on mysql console? What means "not working" ?any errors?

Comment: it says - #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: @swap have changed my answer. try again.

Comment: got this error - #1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Comment: @swap OK you have more than tis two columns in your table. Next try.